# Display selected features with same point geometry

Tags: qgis, geometry, select, color, display

I have a point layer and some features have exactly the same geometry. When I make a selection it seems that some features are not selected because they do not display with the "Selection color" as they are "under" an other feature that is not select.

The only way i find to see my selection is to create a new layer with the the selection and display it on the top of the project layers. It's very "costly"...
Is there an other solution ?

Comment: Yes, this happens to me too... I haven't found a way around it yet!

Comment: See the answer to [QGIS Select overlapped feature](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126819/4972).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are making your selections from the attribute table.

You can actually set up a rule-based symbology, which will make selected features larger than non-selected ones, or even bring them to the forefront.

This requires the Expression Plus plugin.

First create your symbology. Then switch to a Rule Based symbology.

Leave the original rule/rules in place and create a new one. This new one should have a filter of:

**QGIS 2.12+:**

```
isselected( @layer_name )
```

**Or QGIS 2.8:**

```
isselected( 'ACTUAL_NAME_OF_LAYER' )
```

Make the symbology for this one a larger symbol, or a different shape like a star.

Like so:
[image]

You can also set up symbol levels, through the "Advanced" options, and set the selected rule to be a larger number than the other rules.

For more pictures you can check out the guide at:

http://gisforthought.com/highlighting-selections-in-qgis/